# Create a snackbar above the bottom navigation in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Please someone help in it . I want to create a snackbar above the bottom tab bar . I can make it by using the position absolute fir for snackbar component . By making this component absolute the data behind the screen hides it . and i want the data to be above this snackBar. If i make the position relative of the snackBar then it goes below the bottom tab bar . I have to implement this functionality using react native . Someone having any idea about it please help.